# Rewrite condition is not working

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, opencart

How to rewrite the URL for my search page in opencart that is like

```
http://IP/opencart/index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=24
```

But I need to display it like

```
http://localhost/opencart/product/search/42
```

orelse in any formate that is an userfreindly.I have tried like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /opencart
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteBase /opencart 
RewriteRule ^search$ index.php?route=product/search  [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/search$
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^opencart/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /opencart/index.php?route=$1/$2&filter_name=$3 [L]
```

Please note that the slash in the route parameter complicates things.

Comment: In your webroot create a file called .htaccess and add the content from my answer. Also above the RewriteBase line add a line saying RewriteEngine On

Comment: I know @Ruben but on which line i need to put that....You can see my htaccess file content on my question

Comment: Just put it directly below the RewriteEngine On line.

Comment: Eeeh, you'll need to be more specific.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33240/discussion-between-gautam3164-and-ruben)