# how can i manage url using .htaccess in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i want to manage url of my website

right now its showing me www.computermall.co.in/product_details.php?prdid=34

but i want www.computermall.co.in/product_details/34

how can i do it?

i have tried this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /computermall

# Get the URI-path directly from THE_REQUEST variable
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\s/(.*)\.php [NC]
# Strip the extension and redirect permanently
RewriteRule  .*   /%2   [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php  [NC]
# Map internally to the original resource
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Me also want to know the answer....

Comment: yaa man i have tried a lot but no result

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product_details/prdid/([^/]*)$ /product_details?prdid=$1 [L]
```

Edit: removed leading slash

Comment: its not working...may i know where should i add this code? should i add RewriteEngine On again?

Comment: Add it in a file called .htaccess and put it in the web root directory.

Comment: Same condition for me also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585088/rewrite-condition-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `RewriteBase /computermall` is confusing but i am assuming thats there because your domain is in a sub directory of another active domain/http server path.

Here is your `htaccess`

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^computermall/product_details/([^/]*)/([^/]*$ /computermall/product_details?prdid=$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: actually right now i am working on localhost...and this is my url on localhost....  
http://localhost/computermall/product_details?prdid=28

Comment: Same condition for me also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585088/rewrite-condition-is-not-working

Comment: i have tried this and its showing me internal server error.....

Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^product_details/([^/]*)/([^/]*$ /computermall/product_details?prdid=$2 [R=301,L]

Comment: actually product_details is my page name called product_details.php but i have tried above code which i have written while asking question...so that its hiding .php extension